# No sound after update of 16.04, restored with kernel rollback

Tags: 16.04, kernel, xubuntu

This morning, I got prompted to do a software update which I allowed to proceed.

Then my sound stopped working.

I had just recently deleted all older kernels so couldn't roll back. I used an app called "ukuu" to get back an older kernel and now my sound works.

The kernel that didn't work is linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic

The one I rolled back to that does work is linux-image-4.12.14-041214-generic

Anyone else run into this? Did I do the right thing?

ALso, this site (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack) makes it seem that a kernel update might have happened here.

Can anyone shed any light here? I had been updating the system regularly with no problems and this is the first time encountering this issue.

Comment: If the only difference is a change of kernels, then please file a bug report against the 'linux' package.

Comment: Not exactly sure how to do that - can you point me to somewhere to learn how to file such a bug report?

Comment: Oh...bug reports need to be pretty certain and exact about the problem. Developers do not have unlimited time to do basic troubleshooting, so they don't. Ubuntu participants (like you and me) are expected to learn the basic troubleshooting and proper reporting skills. to improve Open Source software like the Linux Kernel. Use the 'Search' feature to ask questions like 'how do I troubleshoot <my problem>' or 'how do I report this bug'.

Comment: see [How do I report a bug?](//askubuntu.com/q/5121)

Comment: Got it! I followed the instructions at the end of Step 3 here and it worked. I guess the Alsa drivers needed an update after the kernel update.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: Not sure who to contact, but this post got flagged as "put on hold as off-topic". Not sure what is off-topic about this post. I don't think it was a bug per se, but rather caused by a back level version of sound drivers. Please let me know what I should change to be compliant. Or if it's easier, just delete the whole thread since the answer was in a well known area of Ubuntu support.